# Remove error labels of jQueryValidator

Tags: jquery-validate, label

When validating a form, how do I indicate that I do not want the error labels to be generated?

I tried using `errorElement: ""` but when I validate the form a second time the textbox's disapear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about this?

```
$("#myform").validate({
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) { //just nothing, empty  },
   ...
 })
```

Comment: "errorPlacement: null" doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

When I want more control over error messages, I tend to create divs or adjust css styles to highlight issues instead of using the standard error labels.

```
jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";
var validator = $("#formID").validate({
        invalidHandler: function(e, validator){
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors > 0)
            // Create Div to show big red warning that the form was invalid
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

also just give below that errorElement

```
messages:
   {
      Control Name:""
   }
```

Comment: Your example will remove the text, but if there is a color border around the text, that border will remain visible to the user.